# Is there a way to tell a very gory story while still being PG-13 when writing a comic book?

Tags: comics

Is there a way to tell a very gory story while still being PG-13 when writing a comic book? What are some techniques used in order to insure that? I see some comic books like Berserk that are extremely graphic and I am wondering if we can tell the exact same story by using artistic techniques to make it PG-13 without using black bars or any other "non-artistic" methods of censoring violence and gore.

Comment: Well, if you want to show the gore, you could give it an unnatural color. I've seen rainbow puke often enough. Not showing the gore in the first place makes it even easier. Have fun with it, have a teddy-bear stand in for a demonstration of evisceration, etc. And I mean, let's be honest here, Little Red Riding Hood has a wolf eating a grandmother and a kid, then getting cut open, stuffed with rocks, sown up and dropped down a well. How is that not gory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an existing image has to be censored after the fact (for example because you're republishing an existing comic in a country more sensitive to how violence in portrayed in media aimed at children), you pretty much *have* to resort to obvious censoring via black bars or pixelation. If you have a bit more control, you may be able to crop out offending parts of an image or cover them up by changing the placement of a speech bubble. Sometimes, it might be possible to skip entire pages.

But if you're creating the entire comic from scratch, it's completely up to you what to show and what to hide. Instead of actually showing the gory parts, you could use **discretion shots**. For example, instead of showing an entire dead body, you just show an arm stretched out unnaturally on the floor, and let the characters' reaction tell the rest of the story. Or someone opens a door and recoils in horror, but you don't actually show the bloodbath in the room beyond.

If your comic is in black and white, showing blood might be less problematic in general. But even if it's in colour, you could use shadows and lighting to make it seem less realistic, especially when combined with discretion shots. So you only show a few droplets of a dark liquid instead of a puddle of what's obviously blood.